# Looking for an IOS version of ShowcaseView

Tags: ios

I'm looking for a library similar to https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView

I want to be able to implement forced tutorials on new users who open my application for the first time. Does anyone know where I can find a library that helps make this easy?

Answer (score 0):

You ca try https://github.com/rahuliyer95/iShowcase 
This is a quite similar iOS implementation of the ShowcaseView for Android (https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView).